# char function in fprintf matlab: keeping new lines when writing to file

Tags: matlab, char, fopen

I am trying to pass a `char()` function's output to `fprintf` so that I can write multiple lines to a text file. The problem is that `fprintf(fid,'%s\n', str)` is neglecting all the blank spaces between the lines, and prints one large line instead. I'd like to print the `str`, without the loss of the new lines.

```
str = (char(textlinepre));
filename = 'newfile.dat';
fid = fopen(filename,'w');
fprintf(fid,'%s\n', str);    
fclose(fid);
```

Original dat/text file content, which is read in as a cell array of strings to the variable `textlinepre`.

```
%Created with Spacar 2.0.25 at 18-05-17, 11:43:37

% leafspring1
BEAM        1   1    2   3    4   0.0000000000   1.0000000000   0.0000000000
% solid bar
BEAM        2   3    4   5    6   0.0000000000   0.0000000000   1.0000000000
% leafspring2
BEAM        3   5    6   7    8   0.0000000000   1.0000000000   0.0000000000

   X        1   0.0000000000   0.0000000000   0.0000000000
   X        3   0.0000000000   0.1000000000   0.1000000000
   X        5   0.0000000000   0.0000000000   0.1000000000
   X        7   0.0000000000   0.1000000000   0.0000000000

FIX 1 1
FIX 1 2
FIX 1 3
FIX 2 2
FIX 2 3
FIX 2 4
FIX 7 1
FIX 7 2
FIX 7 3
FIX 8 2
FIX 8 3
FIX 8 4

RLSE 3 1
RLSE 3 2
RLSE 3 3
RLSE 3 4
RLSE 3 5
RLSE 3 6

DYNE 1 1
DYNE 1 2
DYNE 1 3
DYNE 1 4
DYNE 1 5
DYNE 1 6


END
HALT

XF 3 0.000000000000 0.000000000000 0.000000000000

EM 1 0.070650000000 0.000001909022 0.000001907550 0.000000001472 0.000000000000
EM 2 1.999400000000 0.000094804883 0.000066646667 0.000028158217 0.000000000000
EM 3 0.070650000000 0.000001909022 0.000001907550 0.000000001472 0.000000000000

ESTIFF 1 1890000.000000000000 0.058028906301 51.030000000000 0.039375000000 0.000000000000 0.000000000000
ESTIFF 3 1890000.000000000000 0.000000000000 0.000000000000 0.039375000000 0.000000000000 0.000000000000

EDAMP 1 0.365400000000 0.000006500000 0.000190000000 0.000005300000
EDAMP 3 0.365400000000 0.000000000000 0.000000000000 0.000005300000

TIMESTEP        10.00 50
ITERSTEP 10 10 0.00005

END
END

VISUALIZATION
BEAMVIS  1 0.000500000000 0.018000000000
BEAMVIS  2 0.013000000000 0.020000000000
BEAMVIS  3 0.000500000000 0.018000000000

VIBRATIONMODE 1
VIBREND 7.854
ENLARGEFACTOR 0.01
TRANSPARENCY 0.6
```

Comment: Yes you are right, I am sorry, I tried editing it into a more clear formulation.

Comment: Give us an example of what `textlinepre` is? You are currently just printing a new line after your entire string, not at given points within it...

Comment: What I do not get is how to insert an enter after each string (line).

Comment: see the answer below, you can use `sprintf` to build the string correctly.

Comment: What variable type is `textlinepre`? A cell array of strings? With all the quotes in your example, it can't be pasted in as one string...

Comment: A cell array of strings indeed. This not the right way to copy and paste text from a file to another file then?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a cell array of strings (in your case you get this from an external file)

```
textlinepre = {'line1', 'line2', 'line3'};
```

Write to file

```
filename = 'newfile.dat';
fid = fopen(filename,'w');
% Print to file line by line, so '\n' is added after every element
for ii = 1:numel(textlinepre)
    fprintf(fid, '%s\n', textlinepre{ii}); 
end
fclose(fid);
```

Here is a mathworks example for doing exactly this: [Export cell array to text file](https://www.mathworks.com/examples/matlab/mw/matlab-ex07445498-export-cell-array-to-text-file)

Comment: This worked perfectly fine! My gratitude is great :)

Answer (score 0):

There must be something wrong with the way you build textlinepre. I have the code below and it works fine

```
textlinepre = sprintf(['%% leafspring1\n' ...
                       'BEAM 1 1 2 3 4 0.0000000000 1.0000000000 0.0000000000\n'...
                       '%% solid bar\n'...
                       'BEAM 2 3 4 5 6 0.0000000000 0.0000000000 1.0000000000\n'...
                       '%% leafspring2\n'...
                       'BEAM 3 5 6 7 8 0.0000000000 1.0000000000 0.0000000000\n\n'...
                       'X 1 0.0000000000 0.0000000000 0.0000000000']);
str = (char(textlinepre));

filename = 'newfile.dat';
fid = fopen(filename,'w');
fprintf(fid,'%s\n', str); 
fclose(fid);
```

Comment: I think the OP is not building the string manually. textlinepre comes from a file on the disk.

Comment: This means you have to do it all manually right? Textlinepre is substracted from another textfile, doing it manually would be rather difficult since its quite a few lines.

Comment: @S.Hoefsloot Can you upload the real text file to get "textlinepre" because the value of "textlinepre" you posted above is an invalid Matlab statement.

Comment: @AmritbirSinghGill I do not think it is possible to upload a file here. But the text file has the following content, added in the original post.

Comment: You are correct, the only files which can be added to a post here are images, but your clarification (above) that your text is a cell array is enough.